# md-tooltip within img tag in Angular Material

Tags: html, angular-material

I want to show 3 different tooltips on hovering on 3 different images:

```
<md-menu md-position-mode="target-left target" >
    <img src="assets/img/silver1.png">
        <md-tooltip md-direction="'right'">
            4 silver badges
        </md-tooltip>
    </img>
    <img src="assets/img/gold1.png">2
        <md-tooltip md-direction="'right'">
            2 gold badges
        </md-tooltip>
    </img>
    <img src="assets/img/platinum1.png">1 
        <md-tooltip md-direction="'right'">
            1 platinum badge
        </md-tooltip>
     </img>
</md-menu>
```

But on hovering on any of the images, I'm getting the tooltip which is declared at the last (1 platinum badge). Any idea on how to solve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not been able to do this within the `img` tag.
The workaround can be to wrap the `img` tag within a `span` tag like this:

```
<md-menu md-position-mode="target-left target" >
   <span>
    <img src="assets/img/silver1.png">
        <md-tooltip md-direction="'right'">
            4 silver badges
        </md-tooltip>
   </span>
   <span>
    <img src="assets/img/gold1.png">2
        <md-tooltip md-direction="'right'">
            2 gold badges
        </md-tooltip>
   </span>
   <span>
    <img src="assets/img/platinum1.png">1 
        <md-tooltip md-direction="'right'">
            1 platinum badge
        </md-tooltip>
   </span>
</md-menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach I found to work was by using a button. Take the following example where I am applying the tooltip to an image:

```
                        <button mat-flat-button #tooltip="matTooltip"
                        [matTooltip]="user.name"
                        matTooltipPosition="above"
                        aria-label="Profile image button which displays tooltip when hovered over."
                        class="profile-button">
                            <img class="profile-img" src="[your_image.png]">
                        </button>
```