# Angular Material - md-tooltip in md-list-item's img

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to use an `md-tooltip` for a favicon contained within an `md-list-item`. The intended behaviour is for the tooltip to fire when the mouse is hovering over the icon. Here is the code:

```
<md-list-item ng-repeat="window in windows track by window.id" ng-click="restoreWindow($index)">
  <div ng-repeat="tab in window.tabs.slice(0, 4) track by tab.id">
    <img class="tab-favicon" src="{{tab.favIconUrl}}">
    <md-tooltip>{{tab.title}}</md-tooltip>
  </div>
</md-list-item>
```

Unfortunately, the `md-tooltip`s fail to fire when using the above code. I've also tried the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33854664/md-tooltip-within-img-tag-in-angular-material) and that didn't work either.

A possible solution involves placing `img` and `md-tooltip` inside an `md-button`, but that makes the spaces between each icon way too large. Overriding the `md-button`'s margin in CSS failed to fix this spacing issue.